# Getting "Bad Disk" and unbootable/readable disk after "Convert MBR Disk to GPT Disk" (Minitool PW)

Tags: data-recovery, mbr, gpt, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

I was having my MBR disk with my main OS (Windows 10) and many important files on it.
My disk is ***Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB Sata*** with good health.
I have run ***Convert MBR Disk to GPT Disk*** on it and applied changes using **Minitool Partition Wizard Technician 12.1** bootable usb.
The process completed without showing any error messages, and before I quit Minitool to try to boot my converted disk, I noticed that the disk usage jumped suddenly to 100% however it was just 80%.
When I restarted my system, the disk became undiscoverable/bootable at all, however I tried both UEFI and Legacy Boot.
I booted to *Minitool Partition Wizard* bootable usb again, and my disk became labeled as ***Bad Disk*** as shown in the screenshot. Also it's read as MBR (not GPT as expected).

I hope I could recover my disk and make it readable again.
I hope I could find a faster solution other than ***Partition Recovery Wizard*** because it takes so long (However I'm running it now for 3 hours now and it didn't find any partition to recover).

Comment: why trying these third party tools when microsoft provides a tool for same thing https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt ? and that too without backups ? will suggest to make full image backup using tools like https://clonezilla.org/ ; you can then try mounting your drives on linux and copy your necessary files somewhere safe if successful

Comment: I already tried mbr2gpt before I go to Minitool. It was giving me `"Cannot find room for the EFI system partition"` consistently hiwever I had 80Gb free space on disk. And I tried many suggested solutions online to make it work without hope, so I went to Minitool.

Comment: Unfortunately I went without any backup. That's the whole idea for MBR to GPT conversion in place, it lets you quickly convert disk without needing to have large backups, ~400GB in my case. I know this is a mistake I've made that I trusted that things could go without problems.

Comment: Can mounting disk on linux without taking image backup be unsafe? because taking an image backup may need a day or half a day at best.

Comment: can't say anything whether it will will work or mess it up even more ; taking backup is your choice and depends on importance of data - decide wisely ; `"Cannot find room for the EFI system partition"` points out that for some reason it was not able to create the efi poartition , 80gb free space doesn't matter ; attach some pics showing your partition structure - will help to figure out out what went wrong ; also you can can try running chkdsk if you haven't ; there are tools in linux like gdisk to see if your partition table is ok or corrupted and can help you repair it if needed

Comment: also it's unclear which screenshot you referring to in original post; if you proceed without backup you can try mounting with read only - will be little safe ; let's hope for the best - good luck mate !